# Gatling gives error when using parameter for ramp

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I'm using a parameter for my ramp value as per the docs,

```
val rampUpRate  = Integer.getInteger("ramp", 1)

setUp(
    scn.users(10).ramp(rampUpRate).protocolConfig(httpConf)
)
```

But when I run gatling, I'm getting an error:

```
09:57:35.695 [ERROR] c.e.e.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - /Gatling/user-files/simulations/clients/com/mydomain/www/stress/RecordedSimulation.scala:1088: overloaded method value ramp with alternatives:
  (duration: akka.util.Duration)com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.scenario.configuration.ConfiguredScenarioBuilder <and>
  (duration: Long)com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.scenario.configuration.Configured
ScenarioBuilder
 cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer)
```

I thought I could simply cast to Long before using the parameter

```
val rampUpRate  = Integer.getInteger("ramp", 1)

setUp(
    scn.users(10).ramp((Long) rampUpRate).protocolConfig(httpConf)
)
```

but this still errors:

```
09:57:35.695 [ERROR] c.e.e.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - /Gatling/user-files/simulations/clients/com/mydomain/www/stress/RecordedSimulation.scala:1088: \sanctuarySpa\com\sanctuaryspa\www\stress\RecordedSimulation.scala:1088:
value rampUpRate is not a member of object Long
10:05:34.915 [ERROR] c.e.e.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - scn1.users(10).ramp((Long) rampUpRate).protocolConfig(httpConf),
```

Any suggestions why following the documentation, or the explicit cast to long don't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `rampUpRate.toLong` to cast to a Long (or the more general cast `rampUpRate.asInstanceOf[Long]`)

`(Long) rampUpRate` is seen by the compiler as trying to perform `Long.rampUrRate()` e.g. applying function `rampUpRate` to `object Long`, hence the error message

Comment: rampUpRate.toLong works perfectly, and thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

That's my fault: the wiki page is not up to date.
What happens is that you have a java.lang.Integer while the method takes a scala Long. java.lang.Long can be implicitly converted into scala Long, but not java.lang.Integer.

The proper way would be `val rampUpRate  = java.lang.Long.getLong("ramp", 1L)`

PS: I've fixed the doc.

Comment: Thanks Stephane, and I'm really finding Gatling a great tool to work with once I'm getting these little quirks resolved

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to BGR for helping here. Gatling 2 will be even better!

Comment: Definitely looking forward to version 2 then